# Find index of max element

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, max

I am having trouble getting the index where the greatest element is found. I know elements in the array can be accessed by X[r], where r is the index and that is what I did here, but I can not seem to get it get the index only.

Code:

```
public class Max {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] B = {-1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 2, -3, -2, 11, 5, 7};
    System.out.println("max = " + maxArrayIndex(B, 0, B.length-1));
}

static int maxArrayIndex(int[] X, int p, int r) {
    int q = 0;
    if(p < r) {
       q = (p + r)/2;
       int maxLeft = maxArrayIndex(X, p, q);
       int maxRight = maxArrayIndex(X, q+1, r);
       int maxFinal = max(maxLeft, maxRight);
       return maxFinal;
      }
      return X[r];
   }

   static int max(int p , int r) {
       int maxIndex = 0;
       if(p > r) {
          maxIndex = p;
       } else {
           maxIndex = r;
       }
       return maxIndex;
     }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, its what they are made for.

Comment: As @dambros said in your maxArrayIndex() and max() functions you are returning the max value to compare against the other side max (maxLeft and maxRight) so you are not getting the index anywhere. You are confusing yourself at naming the max parameters p and r as well as your local variable maxIndex when they are not index

Comment: maxArrayIndex should return r not  return X[r];

Comment: This seems like a strange problem to solve with a recursive, divide-and-conquer approach.  If recursion is a requirement, why not tail recursion?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Max {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] B = {-1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 2, -3, -2, 11, 5, 7};
        System.out.println("max = " + maxArrayIndex(B, 0, B.length - 1));
    }

    static int maxArrayIndex(int[] X, int p, int r) {
        int q = 0;
        if (p < r) {
            q = (p + r) / 2;
            int maxLeft = maxArrayIndex(X, p, q);
            int maxRight = maxArrayIndex(X, q + 1, r);
            int maxFinal = max(X, maxLeft, maxRight);
            return maxFinal;
        }
        // Changed from X[r] to r. This will return the index instead of the element.
        return r;
    }

    // Added X parameter.
    static int max(int[] X, int p, int r) {
        int maxIndex = 0;

        // Changed to compare the elements of the indexes,
        // instead of comparing the indexes themselves.
        if (X[p] > X[r]) {
            maxIndex = p;
        } else {
            maxIndex = r;
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
}
```

Suggested Alternative:

```
static int maxArrayIndex(int[] X, int p, int r) {
    int currentMaxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        if(X[i] > X[currentMaxIndex]){
            currentMaxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return currentMaxIndex;
}
```

Comment: I ran it with different arrays to be sure. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `maxArrayIndex` & max method like this,you have to again call `max` outside of `if` block,rest of the code is OK.

**Problem in your code**:You have to pass array `X` to the `max` method to get the index of the larger element,right now you are just finding the larger index.

```
static int maxArrayIndex(int[] X, int p, int r) {
int q = 0;
if(p < r) {
   q = (p + r)/2;
   int maxLeft = maxArrayIndex(X, p, q);
   int maxRight = maxArrayIndex(X, q+1, r);
   return max(X,maxLeft, maxRight);
  }
  return max(X,p,r);
}


static int max(int X[],int p , int r) {
   int maxIndex = 0;
   if(X[p] > X[r]) {
      maxIndex = p;
   } 
   else {
      maxIndex = r;
   }
   return maxIndex;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try running this?

Comment: @robotlos i modified the code, I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's seem you are never checking the element inside the array and you return the value of the index at the end.

```
 static int max(int[] X , int maxIndex) {
    for (int i = 1; i <  X.length; i++){
       int currentNumber=  X[i];
       if ((currentNumber>  X[maxIndex])){
       maxIndex = i;
      }
    } 
    return maxIndex; 
}
```

Check this question It's look pretty much what you are trying to do: 
[How can I locate and print the index of a max value in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991103/how-can-i-locate-and-print-the-index-of-a-max-value-in-an-array)

Comment: I think OP wants to know what the problem is with HIS algorithm. No?

Comment: Is algo is not doing what he saying it's doing. It's just checking if the index is bigger that the other which is pointless because he is not checking anyElement in is array.