# Printing the index of an array element after choosing the largest element

Tags: java, arrays

First of all I'm sorry if there is any mistake in the title of this question. I just don't know how to put it in a question. The following code rolls a dice thousand times and displays how many times a number on the dice is rolled. I want to print the index of the largest number not the element.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class apples {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a[] = new int[7];

    for(int i = 1; i<1001; i++){
        ++a[rand.nextInt(6) + 1];
    }
    System.out.println("Roll\tTimes");

    for(int j=1; j<a.length; j++){
        System.out.println(j + "\t\t" + a[j]);
    }
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i : a) {
        if (max < i) {
            max = i;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("The winning number is " + max);

}

}
```

EDIT:

I figured how to get the index but is there an easier way to do it?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class apples {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a[] = new int[7];
    int winner = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i<1001; i++){
        ++a[rand.nextInt(6) + 1];
    }
    System.out.println("Roll\tTimes");

    for(int j=1; j<a.length; j++){
        System.out.println(j + "\t\t" + a[j]);
    }
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i : a) {
        if (max < i) {
            max = i;

        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++){
        if(max==a[j]){
            winner = j;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The winning number is " + winner);

}

}
```

Comment: than rewrite the foreach to a normal for loop. instead of storing the value of the array at a given pos into the max, store the index there, and compare against the value at the index where your current max val is, instead of comparing against the number.

Comment: I opened another loop with an if statement to check if the value of max is equal to an array element and then assigned the index to another variable then printed it.... But is there any other way it can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I locate and print the index of a max value in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991103/how-can-i-locate-and-print-the-index-of-a-max-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will not be able to get the index of the array (directly) if you use for-each loop** (like how you did), rather you need to use normal `for` loop as shown below in the code with comments:

```
int max = a[0];
int maxIndex = 0;//take a variable & Initialize to 0th index
for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {//normal for loop, not for each
    if (max < a[i]) {
        max = a[i];
        maxIndex = i;//capture the maxIndex
    }
}
System.out.println(": maxIndex :"+maxIndex);//print the maxIndex
```

Comment: Thanks. I got confused that if i do what you said i will always get the index as 6.

Comment: no, there is if condition, so maxIndex will be assigned the value only when there is a bigger value

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `foreach` to indexed `for` loop and keep a track of index of largest number.

Change this part to

```
int max = a[0];
   for (int i : a) {
      if (max < i) {
        max = i;

    }
}
```

Change it with

```
    int max = a[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0, aLength = a.length; j < aLength; j++) {
        int i = a[j];
        if (max < i) {
            max = i;
            index = j;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The winning number is " + max);
    System.out.println("The winning index is " + index);
```

This will print the lasrgest number in which roll it was achieved.